# Debugging foreach in R using dorng

Tags: r, foreach

I am parallelizing a task in R using `foreach` loop with reproducible results using the `dorng` operator. It is a complex code, and I have an error that I have not been able to identify even though I have run the same code with a regular `for` loop.

My fundamental question is: how do I debug a function within of a `foreach` loop assuming that I have reproducible results? Below is my current tentative.

In the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doRNG/vignettes/doRNG.pdf) of the doRNG package, it says that a sequence of random seeds will be generated and set at the beginning of each iteration using the R number generator "L’Ecuyer-CMRG". The sequence of random seeds can be defined using `set.seed` before the `foreach` loop:

```
library(doRNG)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

registerDoParallel(2)
set.seed(1234)
f01 <- foreach(i = 1:100, .combine = 'c')  %dorng% {
  out <- 1 + i
}
r01 <- attr(f01, "rng")

set.seed(1234)
f02 <- foreach(i = 1:100, .combine = 'c')  %dorng% {
  out <- 1 + i
}
r02 <- attr(f02, "rng")
```

The objects `r01` and `r02` contain the sequence of seeds used in `f01` and `f02`,

```
identical(f01, f02)
identical(r01, r02)
```

such that the results from the `foreach` loop and their seeds are identical as expected!

Then, let's consider the case when the `foreach` loop will give me a random error:

```
set.seed(1234)
f03 <- foreach(i = 1:100, .combine = 'c')  %dorng% {
  u <- floor(runif(1, 1, 101))
  
  if (i == as.integer(u)){
    out <- "a" + "b"
  } else {
    out <- 1 + i
  }

}
Error in { : task 67 failed - "non-numeric argument to binary operator"
```

The error occurs at iteration 67 and it is very easy to understand the error. Unfortunately, it is not the same in my case.

I would like to be able to use `debug` and walk through my function to understand the error. From the best of my knowlegde, I cannot use `debug` inside a `foreach` loop in R.

Then, I thought about capturing the error in a regular `for` loop, but running my code is very slow and, apparently, I cannot observe the error with a low number of iterations. I need to understand the error using `foreach`.

Although I can't recover the sequence of seeds from `f03`, I know that they will be identical to `r01` or `r02`. For iteration 67, I have

```
r01[[67]]
[1]       10407  1484283582  -741709185   513087691   132931819
[6]  1318506528 -1383054295
```

Therefore, I guess that fixing my seed at `r01[[67]]` should give me the same error:

```
i <- 67
set.seed(r01[[67]], kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
u <- floor(runif(1, 1, 101))
  if (i == as.integer(u)){
    out <- "a" + "b"
  } else {
    out <- 1 + i
}
u
[1] 74
```

which is not true.

In the doRNG [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doRNG/vignettes/doRNG.pdf), page 6, they have an example of using a seed in a loop from a previous loop:

```
set.seed(1234)
ex01 <- foreach(i=1:5) %dorng% { runif(3) }
ex02 <- foreach(i=1:5, .options.RNG=attr(ex01, 'rng')[[2]]) %dorng% { runif(3) }
identical(ex02[1:4], ex01[2:5])
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue comes from the fact that `doRNG` gives you the random seed state and you're using that as the input of `set.seed`, which requires just an integer. I expect `set.seed` is only taking the first integer provided to the function to set the random seed state. Instead, what you should do is set the seed state in R. First I get the seed states and verify I can reproduce the error:

```
library(doRNG)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

registerDoParallel(2)
kind <- RNGkind()
kind
[1] "Mersenne-Twister" "Inversion"        "Rejection"   

set.seed(1234, kind = kind[1]) #explicitly set RNG kind so I can reproduce more easily if I run the code multiple times
f01 <- foreach(i = 1:100, .combine = 'c')  %dorng% {
  out <- 1 + i
}
r01 <- attr(f01, "rng")

set.seed(1234, kind = kind[1])
f03 <- foreach(i = 1:100, .combine = 'c')  %dorng% {
  u <- floor(runif(1, 1, 101))
  
  if (i == as.integer(u)){
    out <- "a" + "b"
  } else {
    out <- 1 + i
  }

}
Error in { : task 39 failed - "non-numeric argument to binary operator"
```

I got a different iteration number for the failure. Not sure why but I still get the error as you did. Then I see if we can replicate by setting `.Random.seed` directly:

```
i <- 39
RNGkind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
.Random.seed <- r01[[39]]
u <- floor(runif(1, 1, 101))
  if (i == as.integer(u)){
    out <- "a" + "b"
  } else {
    out <- 1 + i
}
Error in "a" + "b" : non-numeric argument to binary operator
u
[1] 39
```

Looks like we can! Full code below:

```
library(doRNG)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

registerDoParallel(2)
kind <- RNGkind()
kind

set.seed(1234, kind = kind[1]) #explicitly set RNG kind so I can reproduce more easily if I run the code multiple times
f01 <- foreach(i = 1:100, .combine = 'c')  %dorng% {
  out <- 1 + i
}
r01 <- attr(f01, "rng")

set.seed(1234, kind = kind[1])
f02 <- foreach(i = 1:100, .combine = 'c')  %dorng% {
  out <- 1 + i
}
r02 <- attr(f02, "rng")

identical(f01, f02)
identical(r01, r02)

set.seed(1234, kind = kind[1])
f03 <- foreach(i = 1:100, .combine = 'c')  %dorng% {
  u <- floor(runif(1, 1, 101))
  
  if (i == as.integer(u)){
    out <- "a" + "b"
  } else {
    out <- 1 + i
  }

}

identical(r01, r03)

i <- 39
RNGkind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
.Random.seed <- r01[[39]]
u <- floor(runif(1, 1, 101))
  if (i == as.integer(u)){
    out <- "a" + "b"
  } else {
    out <- 1 + i
}
u

#restore RNG kind to original
RNGkind(kind[1])
```

Comment: This is really interesting. Is there a way to achieve something similar to without using the package doRNG, but rather just using 'parallel::clusterSetRNGStream'? I have a problem similat to that of the OP, and had an error after 22h of runtime. Since I'm already using clusterSetRNGStream  in my script I'd like to know if I can reproduce the exact contidion for the failing task without having to re-run the script with doRNG for other 22h... thanks

Comment: I imagine you could. You just have to figure out the correct value for `.Random.seed`